# SOAP Logic help retrieving and updating data

Tags: php, email, soap

So have been playing with this for a while now.
Pretty new with SOAP to be honest.

Issue is this:
I have documentation which i have been following and i can retrieve one persons profile using the unique ID.

Now i want to receive all users in a certain pool/group/target etc.

here is what i am using:

```
$client = new SoapClient($pr, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'trace'=>true));
```

and the code is like so:

```
 $job_info = $client->getByTargetGroup(16520);
```

also tried this

```
 $job_info = $client->getByTargetGroup(16520, array('NAME','EMAIL','FIRSTNAME') );
```

In the documentation of the soap i get this info:

parameters type **getByTargetGroup**

**targetgroup_id** type int

**pool_attribute_list** - nillable; type ArrayOfString

```
   **item** - optional, unbounded; type string
```

But when executed i get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Receiver] Maximum number of 20 active jobs exceeded for this customer
```

Am i using SOAP correctly? or reading the documentation incorrectly?

I am just doing this to view feedback

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $job_info);
echo "</pre>";
```

Image link to the documentation:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQjt5.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the WSDL file?

Comment: The error points to exceeding the number of jobs you can trigger. You will need to check the documentation around rate limits/trouble shooting. No doubt your request is incorrect, but looks like you have locked the system for the time being.

Comment: The link to the WSDL file will expose to much information, but i will try and screen shot and remove personal data!

Comment: Does this help
http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/51ef64

Comment: any pointers or help will be much appreciated :)